# unityのtextの軸を左上にするには

Tags: unity3d

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ui>textでテキストを挿入すると左下に軸ができてしまい、
常に下揃えのような感じになってしまいます。
左上を軸にしたいのですが、どうしたらよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

インスペクターで、Alignmentを選べますね。
[image: インスペクター]